# jqGrid column chooser doesn't sort the column order when adding a 'done' callback

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm having the columnchooser all working well.
When I'm adding the 'done' call back function (even an empty one), all working well but the order of the columns - seems like any order I put don't have an effect.

Here is the code:

```
$('#jqGrid').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#jqGridPager', {
            caption: "",
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
            title: "Choose columns",
            onClickButton: function () {
                $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('columnChooser',{
                    width: 550, 
                    msel_opts: {dividerLocation: 0.5}, 
                    modal: true,
                    //To Do - calling the done event cancelling the reorder of the column - need to find out why.
                    done: function() {
                        $('#jqGrid').setGridParam({ postData:sessionListData(pageOffset,sortingAddition,pageLength,$(this))  }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                        $(window).resize(function() { 
                            sessionList(pageOffset,$(this),sortingAddition,pageLength);
                            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGridWidth', $('.ui-layout-center').width() + 5, true);
                        }).trigger('resize');



                    }
                });
                $("#colchooser_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + ' div.available>div.actions')
                    .prepend('<label style="float:left;position:relative;margin-left:0.6em;top:0.6em">Search:</label>');

                var d=$("div.ui-dialog[aria-labelledby='ui-dialog-title-colchooser_list']");
                d.height(530);
                $("div#colchooser_list").height(400);
                $("div.selected, div.available").height(350);
                $("div.selected, div.available","div#colchooser_list").height(350);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug. It's behavior described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#options). You can imagine `done` as virtual method which you can overwrite. By overwriting you have to implement the behavior of the original callback.

Comment: Thanks!  Works now :-)